# how to filter multi dimensional array object

Tags: javascript, json

I want to filter this array by `attributevalue` for example
if I do a search by color blue then all shirts give me a blue color then I do search fabric cotton in blue color then give all cottob with blue color you know search by like flipkart, amazon

```
var myObject=    [
                {
                    "Product-name": "Shirt",
                    "product-price": "500",
                    "attributevalue": [
                        { "color": "red" },
                        {"fabric": "cottton"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Product-name": "Samsung mobile",
                    "product-price": "15000",
                    "attributevalue":[
                        {"Ram": "4 GB"},
                        {"Network": "4G"},
                        {"Primary Camera": "8 MP"},
                        {"Internal Memory": "8 GB"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried to accomplish the desired result?

Comment: Do you want to filter by one attribute? or by multiple attributes?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine`filter`, `for` and `for...in` to do that:

```js
var myObject=    [
                {
                    "Product-name": "Shirt",
                    "product-price": "500",
                    "attributevalue": [
                        { "color": "red" },
                        {"fabric": "cottton"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Product-name": "Samsung mobile",
                    "product-price": "15000",
                    "attributevalue":[
                        {"Ram": "4 GB"},
                        {"Network": "4G"},
                        {"Primary Camera": "8 MP"},
                        {"Internal Memory": "8 GB"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
            
 const search = (arr, search) => {
  return arr.filter(item => {
    for (var i = 0; i < item.attributevalue.length; i++) {
      for (var key in item.attributevalue[i]) {
        if (item.attributevalue[i][key].toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase()) {
          return item;
        }
      }
    }
   })
 }
 
 console.log(search(myObject, 'red'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just the `filter` method of Array will do the trick.

```js
var myObject = [{
  "Product-name": "Shirt",
  "product-price": "500",
  "attributevalue": [{
    "color": "red"
  }, {
    "fabric": "cottton"
  }]
}, {
  "Product-name": "Samsung mobile",
  "product-price": "15000",
  "attributevalue": [{
    "Ram": "4 GB"
  }, {
    "Network": "4G"
  }, {
    "Primary Camera": "8 MP"
  }, {
    "Internal Memory": "8 GB"
  }]
}]

function findProduct(property, searchField) {
  return myObject.filter((x) => {
    const result = x.attributevalue.filter((y) => y[property] === searchField);
    if (result.length) {
      return x;
    }
  })
}


console.log(findProduct('Network', '4G'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
const filterBy = (obj, attr, query) => 
   obj.filter((prod) => prod.attributevalue && prod.attributevalue[attr] === query);
```

Comment: if you don't add a `return` inside the filter callback this will never work.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to remove the {}

Comment: this still won't work due to the nature of `attributevalue` which is an **array of objects**, hence the `prod.attributevalue[attr]` lookup won't work, unless you first map the array to an object. You should change the approach of the lookup :).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach supporting multiple filtering (multiple keys and values) and multiple support for the key-value check.

The routine is:

- applying filter over the desired object.
- mapping the array of attribute value to a single object holding the key (string) and the value.
- evaluating the searchBy parameter, which holds an object containing the key, which is the searched key and the value that can either be a primitive, an object or a function. If that's a function, it will be evaluated through the argument passed, which is the currently looped value to search on.
- return whether any of the searched criteria match.

```js
var myObject = [
  {
    "Product-name": "Shirt",
    "product-price": "500",
    "attributevalue": [
      { "color": "red" },
      {"fabric": "cottton"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "Product-name": "Samsung mobile",
    "product-price": "15000",
    "attributevalue":[
      {"Ram": "4 GB"},
      {"Network": "4G"},
      {"Primary Camera": "8 MP"},
      {"Internal Memory": "8 GB"}
    ]
  }
];

function filterBy(obj, searchBy) {
  return obj.filter(item => {
    const _assigned = Object.assign({}, ...item.attributevalue);
    return Object.entries(searchBy).some(([k,v]) => {
      return _assigned[k] && (typeof(v) === 'function' ? v.call(null, _assigned[k]) : _assigned[k] === v);
    });
  });
}

// Sample to filter by color and fabric.
console.log(filterBy(myObject, {
  color: 'red',
  fabric: (needle) => needle === 'cottton'
}));

// sample of callback filter that checks whether the "RAM" value exists and is, when lowercase, '4 gb'
console.log(
  filterBy(myObject, {
    Ram: (ram) => {
      return ram && ram.toLowerCase() === '4 gb'
    }
  })
);
```